# Opengl 3.3 doesn't draw anything. Using GLSL 330 Core

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am following the guides from [this site](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/) and have stopped on the lesson 2. At first I have tried wiriting my own code but after it didn't work I have simply taken the code from the site. And it still doesn't draw anything besides the `glClearColor`.

What I have done:

1. Checked compiling and linking. Works fine
2. Checked errors. Not sure if I have done it right but seems like everything's allright (I get a 1280 error but I have read that GLEW can cause it and it can be ignored).
3. Moved the `glUseProgram` through the main loop but didn't get any results.
4. Changed colors and tried modifying shaders. Still nothing

I will post the code I have at the moment (the original code from the site):

## main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int max(int i, int j)
{
    if (i > j) return i;
    return j;
}


GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path, const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Create the shaders
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if (VertexShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while (getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
            VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    // Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if (FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::string Line = "";
        while (getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
            FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Compile Fragment Shader
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Check Fragment Shader
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    // Link the program
    fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);


    // Check the program
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(max(InfoLogLength, int(1)));
    std::cout << "Checking program\n";

    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);
    std::cout << "END";

    return ProgramID;
}


int main(void)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot init glfw";
        return -1;
    }

    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL 



    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context 
    GLFWwindow* window; // (In the accompanying source code, this variable is global) 
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Initialize GLEW 
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; // Needed in core profile 
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);


    // This will identify our vertex buffer
    GLuint vertexbuffer;

    // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

    // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

    // Give our vertices to OpenGL.
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders("res\\vertex.glsl", "res\\fragment.glsl");

    do{

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(programID);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
            );

        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();


    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

## fragment.glsl

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;

void main(){
    color = vec3(1,1,0);
}
```

## vertex.glsl

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
void main(){
gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
 }
```

Comment: This code is not compatible with the core profile. Using vertex array objects (VAO) is required in the core profile.

Comment: @RetoKoradi thank you for the comment. It fixed the situation. Would you mind placing it as an answer so that I could mark it correct?

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I'm in the same position you were and would love some help

Comment: @RakshithRavi I suggest you to take a look at the answer I've accepted. It's been more than a year and I'm not sure how I solved it but the answer did help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenGL Core Profile requires the use of Vertex Array Objects (VAOs). This is in the "Deprecated and Removed Features" of the spec:

> Client vertex and index arrays - all vertex array attribute and element array index pointers must refer to buffer objects. The default vertex array object (the name zero) is also deprecated. Calling VertexAttribPointer when no buffer object or no vertex array object is bound will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error, as will calling any array drawing command when no vertex array object is bound.

The tutorial you are using suggests to use this code as part of your initialization:

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
```

This will be enough to get the tutorial code working. To make productive use of VAOs in more complex applications, you will probably want to create a VAO for each object. This will then track the full vertex setup state for the object, and allow you to set the state with a single `glBindVertexArray()` call before drawing.