# OpenTK GL.DrawElements causing GL_INVALID_OPERATION error

Tags: c#, opengl, opengl-3, opentk

As stated in the title I'm getting a GL_INVALID_OPERATION error from glDrawElements, however, this is only happening in a GL Context above GL 3.1, in a context 3.1 and below it renders properly with no issues. My model is loaded like so:

```
public IModel LoadData( Shape a_Shape ) {
        int VertexStride = BlittableValueType<Vertex>.Stride;
        int IndexStride = sizeof ( uint );

        m_Backing = a_Shape;

        m_GLDataBuffer = GL.GenBuffer( );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_GLDataBuffer );
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( m_Backing.Vertices.Count * VertexStride ), m_Backing.Vertices.ToArray( ), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );

        m_GLIndexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer( );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, m_GLIndexBuffer );
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( m_Backing.Indices.Count * IndexStride ), m_Backing.Indices.ToArray( ), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, VertexStride, 0 );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, VertexStride, ( sizeof ( float ) * 3 ) );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 2, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, VertexStride, ( sizeof ( float ) * 6 ) );
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0 );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0 );
        return this;
    }
```

Where a_Shape is just an arbitrary shape loaded from a file or defined by the user, it contains a List of Vertices, which just contain two Vector3's (Position and Normal) and a Vector2 (TexCoords). I then draw the model with this function:

```
void IModel.Draw( ) {
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, m_GLIndexBuffer );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
        GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles, m_Backing.Indices.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0 ); //This is the line that's producing the Error
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray( 2 );
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
        GL.DisableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0 );
    }
```

As I said this works fine until I try to use a GL Context above version 3.1. I'm really confused by the fact that it just won't work above 3.1. I looked into it and i it says on the OpenGL reference:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an enabled array or the element array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.

I don't quite understand what this means, though. So I suppose my question is this: What could cause glDrawElements to only work in certain contexts, and how could I go about fixing it? Or is it an issue with something in my code that I'm just not seeing?

Any help would be very much appreciated, after about 5 hours trying to figure it out I figured it was time to ask for help.

**UPDATE**

So I've reworked my code to the following:

```
    public IModel LoadData( Shape a_Shape ) {
        m_Backing = a_Shape;

        Single[] Positions = new Single[a_Shape.Vertices.Count * 3];
        Single[] Normals = new Single[a_Shape.Vertices.Count * 3];
        Single[] TexCoords = new Single[a_Shape.Vertices.Count * 2];

        for ( int i = 0; i < Positions.Length; i += 3 ) {
            Positions[i + 0] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Position.X;
            Positions[i + 1] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Position.Y;
            Positions[i + 2] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Position.Z;

            Normals[i + 0] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Normal.X;
            Normals[i + 1] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Normal.Y;
            Normals[i + 2] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Normal.Z;
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < TexCoords.Length; i += 2 ) {
            TexCoords[i + 0] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 2].TexCoord.X;
            TexCoords[i + 1] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 2].TexCoord.Y;
        }

        m_GLVertexArray = GL.GenVertexArray( );
        GL.BindVertexArray( m_GLVertexArray );
        m_GLIndexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer( );
        GL.GenBuffers( 3, m_GLDataBuffers );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, m_GLIndexBuffer );
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( uint ) * a_Shape.Indices.Count ), a_Shape.Indices.ToArray( ), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_GLDataBuffers[0] ); // Bind the Position Buffer
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( Single ) * Positions.Length ), Positions, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_GLDataBuffers[1] ); // Bind the Normal Buffer
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( Single ) * Normals.Length ), Normals, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_GLDataBuffers[2] ); // Bind the TexCoord Buffer
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( Single ) * TexCoords.Length ), TexCoords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 2, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0 );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0 );
        GL.BindVertexArray( 0 );
        return this;
    }
```

For the loading and:

```
    void IModel.Draw( ) {
        GL.BindVertexArray( m_GLVertexArray );
        GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles, m_Backing.Indices.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0 );
        GL.BindVertexArray( 0 );
    }
```

For the drawing, using what I could find out from Reto's comment. I no longer get any GL errors, but now nothing renders at all. I again cannot see the where the issue is.

**EDIT**
Fixed not converting Vertices to Position, Normal, and TexCoord arrays properly.

Comment: You're probably getting a Core Profile context for versions above 3.1, and your code is not compatible with the Core Profile. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336227/opengl-3-3-doesnt-draw-anything-using-glsl-330-core.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I've updated my code using a Vertex Array, however now nothing renders at all. I've updated my main post with my current code.

Comment: I just realized I'm not actually storing the data in my arrays properly. I'll edit my main post to fix this.

Comment: You can request a compatibility profile, if supported.

Comment: I don't see a way to do that with OpenTK, I'll keep looking but it's not something I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my original problem was to use a Vertex Array because of deprecations from OpenGL 3.1 Core to OpenGL 3.2 Core, attempting to render without one throws a GL_INVALID_OPERATION error. Afterwards I had another issue where nothing would render, this was a simple mistake on my part, not rebinding the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. The LoadData method scene in the main post works properly and the final Draw method is as follow:

```
    void IModel.Draw( ) {
        GL.BindVertexArray( m_GLVertexArray );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, m_GLIndexBuffer ); //Rebinding the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER solved the second issue.
        GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles, m_Backing.Indices.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0 );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0 );
        GL.BindVertexArray( 0 );
    }
```

**EDIT**

After further discussion I learned that by unbinding the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` (referred to as IBO from here out) before unbinding the VAO caused the VAO to reference the IBO of ID 0 and not the IBO I wanted it to. Below is the final code that I'm using.

```
    public IModel LoadData( Shape a_Shape ) {
        m_Backing = a_Shape;

        Single[] Positions = new Single[a_Shape.Vertices.Count * 3];
        Single[] Normals = new Single[a_Shape.Vertices.Count * 3];
        Single[] TexCoords = new Single[a_Shape.Vertices.Count * 2];

        for ( int i = 0; i < Positions.Length; i += 3 ) {
            Positions[i + 0] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Position.X;
            Positions[i + 1] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Position.Y;
            Positions[i + 2] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Position.Z;

            Normals[i + 0] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Normal.X;
            Normals[i + 1] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Normal.Y;
            Normals[i + 2] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 3].Normal.Z;
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < TexCoords.Length; i += 2 ) {
            TexCoords[i + 0] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 2].TexCoord.X;
            TexCoords[i + 1] = a_Shape.Vertices[i / 2].TexCoord.Y;
        }

        m_GLVertexArray = GL.GenVertexArray( );
        GL.BindVertexArray( m_GLVertexArray );
        m_GLIndexBuffer = GL.GenBuffer( );
        GL.GenBuffers( 3, m_GLDataBuffers );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, m_GLIndexBuffer );
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( uint ) * a_Shape.Indices.Count ), a_Shape.Indices.ToArray( ), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_GLDataBuffers[0] ); // Bind the Position Buffer
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( Single ) * Positions.Length ), Positions, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_GLDataBuffers[1] ); // Bind the Normal Buffer
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( Single ) * Normals.Length ), Normals, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 1, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_GLDataBuffers[2] ); // Bind the TexCoord Buffer
        GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, ( IntPtr ) ( sizeof ( Single ) * TexCoords.Length ), TexCoords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
        GL.VertexAttribPointer( 2, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0 );
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray( 2 );

        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0 );
        GL.BindVertexArray( 0 );
        GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0 );
        return this;
    }
```

And:

```
void IModel.Draw( ) {
    GL.BindVertexArray( m_GLVertexArray );
    GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles, m_Backing.Indices.Count, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0 );
    GL.BindVertexArray( 0 );
}
```

Comment: The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is part of the VAO state. So if you bind it while setting up the VAO, while the VAO is bound, you won't have to bind it again in the `Draw()` method.

Comment: That's what I'd assumed, and is the reason why I removed the call to rebind it in draw in the first place, as the buffer for the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is being generated, bound and populated after the VAO is generated and bound, but even then I still need to rebind it. Unless I'm confused by what you're saying.

Comment: That should have worked. In the originally posted code, you also had a call to unbind the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. You would of course have to remove that, otherwise the binding stored in the VAO state will be reset again.

Comment: I see that makes sense now, for some reason I thought I needed to unbind it, but now that I think about it the next time I load a model it will bind a new VAO and IBO so there's not really any point to unbinding it in the first place.