# QtOpenGLWidget subclass does not draw anything

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a simple vertex and fragment shader. I use them in a class derived from QtOpenGLWidget.the program is supposed to draw a triangle, but it does not show anything. The glClearColor works fine and I am able to change the background color. When I run the program from command line, the program outputs one single line, but draws nothing:

**QOpenGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( position ): shader program is not linked**

When I insert getGLError after gl commands, none of them report an error.
 here is the class definition:

```
class GLCanvas:public QOpenGLWidget , protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
  QMatrix4x4 matrix;
  QOpenGLShaderProgram* shader;
  GLuint posLocation;
  GLuint colLocation;
  GLuint matLocation;
  void cleanup();
public:
  GLCanvas(QWidget* parent);
  void initializeGL() override;
  void paintGL() override;
  void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;

  QStringList getGLinfo();
};



static const char *vertexShaderSource =
    R"(
    #version 330
    in vec3 position;
    void main()
    {
      gl_Position = vec4(position, 1);
    })";


static const char *fragmentShaderSource =
    R"(
    #version 330
    void main()
    {
       gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4,0.4,0.8,1.0);
    })";

GLCanvas::GLCanvas(QWidget* parent): QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
  setFormat(QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat());
  matrix.setToIdentity();

  posLocation = -1;
  colLocation = -1;
  matLocation = -1;
}


void GLCanvas::initializeGL()
{
    makeCurrent();
    connect(context(), &QOpenGLContext::aboutToBeDestroyed, this, &GLCanvas::cleanup);
    constexpr int glNoError = 0;
    GLenum error = -1;
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(.1f, .1f, .1f, 1.0f);
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != glNoError)
      {
        qDebug() << "glclearcolor failed";
      }

    shader = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);
    shader->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource);
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != glNoError)
      {
        qDebug() << "failed after adding vertex shader.";
      }

    shader->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != glNoError)
      {
        qDebug() << "failed after adding fragment shader.";
      }

    Q_ASSERT(shader->link());


    error = glGetError();
    if (error != glNoError)
      {
        qDebug() << "gl error at link.";
      }
    //colLocation = shader->attributeLocation("color");
    //matLocation = shader->uniformLocation("matrix");

    //shader->release();
    posLocation = shader->attributeLocation("position");
    error = glGetError();
    if (error != glNoError)
      {
        qDebug() << "gl error at link.";
      }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //colLocation = shader->attributeLocation("color");
    //matLocation = shader->uniformLocation("matrix");

    //shader->release();


    //glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

}
//###################################################################

void GLCanvas::paintGL()
{
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     GLfloat vertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.707f, .0f,  0.5f, -0.5f, .0f ,-0.5f, -0.5f, .0f};
     Q_ASSERT(shader->bind());
     shader->setAttributeArray(posLocation, vertices, 3, 0);
     glEnableVertexAttribArray(posLocation);
     glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 3);
/*
     GLfloat lvertices[] = { 0.907f, 0.907f, 0.5f, -0.957f, -0.957f, 0.5f };
     shader->setAttributeArray(posLocation, lvertices, 0, 3);
     glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 2);
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(posLocation);

*/
     //glDisableVertexAttribArray(colLocation);
     shader->release();
  //   qDebug() << getGLinfo();
}

void GLCanvas::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
  Q_UNUSED(w);
  Q_UNUSED(h);
  //matrix.setToIdentity();
  //matrix.perspective(45.0f, w / float(h), 0.01f, 1000.0f);
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}
/*
void GLCanvas::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
Q_UNUSED(event);
}

void GLCanvas::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
Q_UNUSED(event);
}
*/
void GLCanvas::cleanup()
{
    if (shader == nullptr)
          return;
    makeCurrent();
    delete shader;
    //shader = nullptr;
    doneCurrent();
}
```

Comment: What about `GL_TRIANGLES` instead of `GL_LINES`?

Comment: nothing happens. I change GL_TRIANGLES to GL_LINES to see what happens.

Comment: Doesn't `#version 330` imply a `core` profile?  If so then this is possibly a duplicate of ["Opengl 3.3 doesn't draw anything. Using GLSL 330 Core"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336227/opengl-3-3-doesnt-draw-anything-using-glsl-330-core).

Comment: I changed the #version to 130 and default surface format to 3.0, nothing changes. but I will try to learn to use buffer objects and array objects to see what happens.

Comment: The Qt documentation states that, when using `setAttributeArray()`, the specified array will be available once you make a call to `enableAttributeArray(int location)` . Alghouth most probably this function is just a wrapper for `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`, I believe you should try calling it instead of directly invoking the OpenGL API function.

Answer (score 0):

I did everything carefully from the beginning and things worked. probably a stupid mistake was the cause of it all. Thank you all.